# Npm problemn with proxy setup

Tags: node.js, npm

Please, someone, help me to solve this problem I have tried with this commend too
C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\My PC (LAPTOP-AKCIKK9M)\Desktop\sample>npm cache clean --force

**Error:............**

C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\My PC (LAPTOP-AKCIKK9M)\Desktop\sample>
C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\My PC (LAPTOP-AKCIKK9M)\Desktop\sample>npm i node-sass --save-dev
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-sass

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-05T07_36_07_437Z-debug.log

C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\My PC (LAPTOP-AKCIKK9M)\Desktop\sample>

Comment: please attach the npm debug log to the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.